# How to download a specific file from Github traversing through all the folders using command line?

Tags: git, github

I need to download a file (.msi) traverse through all the sub folders of the main/parent  repo and download the file with the extension .msi to my local system  using command line option

Each folder may contain sub folder with versions under that I need to fetch all the .msi files

Note I dont want to use the  git clone option here.

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub API doesn't provide a way to traverse the paths in a repository, and Git doesn't provide a way to list paths remotely.

Since you're working with GitHub, you can use the API to get an [archive URL](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link) which will provide you a tarball or a zip file that includes all of the files in a given revision.  If you use a tarball, you can then use `tar` to extract only the files you're interested in by piping it to something like `tar -xf - --wildcards "*.msi"`.

If you don't want to do that, then you'll need to clone the repository manually.  You can use a shallow clone if you only want to receive one revision and not the entire history.